# sinon.js 1.10, jquery 2.1 and synchronous request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sinon

I try to simulate a server with sinon.js and call it with `jQuery.ajax`. But i can't make it works.

Here's the code :

```
$(function() {
  var server = sinon.fakeServer.create();

  server.respondWith('POST', '/some/test', [200, { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}, JSON.stringify({
    id : 'test',
    value : 'test'
  })]);

  var success = sinon.spy(),
      error = sinon.spy();

  jQuery.ajax({
    url : '/some/test',
    async : false,
    type : 'POST',
    data : JSON.stringify({
      test : 'test'
    }),
    contentType : 'application/json',
    success : success,
    error : error,
  });

  console.log(server.requests[0].status);
  console.log(server.requests[0].method);
  console.log(server.requests[0].url);
  console.log(server.requests[0].requestBody);

  console.log(success.called);
  console.log(error.called);

  server.restore();
});
```

If you try this code, you'll see this output :

```
200
POST
/some/test
{"test":"test"}
false
false
```

According to the first 4 logs, sinon respond to the request. But jQuery never called the success callback (and the error is not called too).
It's like the jQuery ajax request never finish.

Comment: AJAX is async, when you call the console log, the AJAX call is still processing.

Comment: Even if there's a `async : false` in the options ?

Comment: Oh, i did not see that. I don't know then, async false is a bad practice, hence i've never used it.

Comment: I know this is a bad pratice. But i got some ... "legacy code" and i just can't change it :(

Comment: I've had issues testing sync requests with Sinon even without jQuery, and after futzing with it for a while I decided just to disable those tests. If I recall correctly (it's been a while) Sinon wasn't firing the readystatechange event for sync requests, and wasn't setting the correct completed state on its mock XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: I'll try with a sync request in pure javascript to test that. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @RichardConnamacher Thanks. I found the issue in sinon.js code with your info. sinon.js works with an "old synchronous", but not in the "new way".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue comes from sinon.js with jQuery 2.1 : https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/issues/510

jQuery 2.1 makes synchronous ajax request like this :

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', '/some/test', false); 
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.onload = function() {
  console.log('success');
};

req.onerror = function() {
  console.log('error');
};

req.send(JSON.stringify({
  test : 'test'
}));
```

The problem is Sinon doesn't trigger the onload or the onerror callback for a synchronous request. The issue is in the method `setResponseBody` of `FakeXMLHttpRequest`. You can find this code :

```
if (this.async) {
    this.readyStateChange(FakeXMLHttpRequest.DONE);
} else {
    this.readyState = FakeXMLHttpRequest.DONE;
}
```

In recent browsers, XmlHttpRequest trigger the callbacks even for a synchronous request. So this code should be modified in this :

```
if (!this.async) {
    this.readyState = FakeXMLHttpRequest.DONE;
}

this.readyStateChange(FakeXMLHttpRequest.DONE);
```

If you patch sinon.js like that, everything works.